# iTunes Connect Upload: which files to upload

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've added my iOS app to iTunes Connect and is currently trying to upload the binary using `Application Loader`. In the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) is seems that they are uploading a zip file. Should I just make a zip of my complete project or what are they excepting?

Comment: How does xcode knows which app belong to the archive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should upload the binary through Xcode.

It's a good idea to do a clean build first (Clean All Targets), and I usually delete my Build/ directory as well. Then do Build/Build and Archive. Make sure you have a device connected when you do this, and that the app is not in debug mode. Then open the Xcode organizer and select the binary to upload. That's all there is to it. You do not have to zip the files manually.

Comment: Thanks. How can I ensure that the app is not in debug mode?

Comment: Look at the drop down tabs. There are two options: Debug and Release. You want it set to Release.

Comment: Do you have any clue, why I get this warning:
> Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.

I've downloaded my Distribution Certificate and the Distribution Provisioning Profile. Further I've ensured that the Archive Profile in "Edit Scheme" is set to "Release".

Comment: @DennisMadsen Check the "Project Settings" and make sure that under the "Release" mode the correct Provisioning Profile is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is step by step procedure to submit directly from xcode,

Just goto **edit scheme** > **Archive** > select **Release**.
Change your profiles to **distribution** (ios app store).
Select ios Device.
Goto Product> Archive

After completion goto Organizer

Select the **Archive** and click **Distribute**
Select **Submit to iOS AppStore**
Login
Select app, it will be showing app that has **ready for upload** status
Select profile.
Here you go.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should zip your *.app file.